# Sign of Laplacian in a N-Dimensional Space Under Other Specific Conditions

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

Consider that  $f:  \mathbb{R}^N \to  \mathbb{R}  $   is infinite times differentiable and is smooth over the entire domain. Take $N$ to be large. Also at point $\mathbf{x_0}$:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} =1  
$$

and

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} <0  
$$

My question is: What are the conditions required for the Laplacian to be negative? In other words:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2} <0  
$$

If it helps with a bit of stretch the following assumptions are valid too at $\mathbf{x_0}$:

First, $f>>x_i$. But $f$ is not much larger than $Nx_i$

Second, if $r$ is the radial direction in spherical coordinates, $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}>>\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2}$. But $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}$ is not much larger than $N\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i^2}$.

Third, $r$ is larger than the first and second derivatives of $f$.

I'd appreciate it very much if anyone would help me on the answer or refer me to a text.